# How to cache a cloud image in either internal or external memory of an android device

Tags: android

> Hello Android members, am having an android code that is working very well with android devices when an external memory is present. Practically an image from a URL is cached in an external device and displayed well on my app but my question is: Can anyone guide me on how to make the image saved in an internal storage as well in the event that an external memory is not mounted on the device? The images only display on devices having a memory card.

```
public class FileCache {

private File cacheDir;

public FileCache(Context context){
    //Find the dir to save cached images
    if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"TempImages");
    else
        cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
    if(!cacheDir.exists())
        cacheDir.mkdirs();
}

public File getFile(String url){
    String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
    File f = new File(cacheDir, filename);
    return f;

}

public void clear(){
    File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
    if(files==null)
        return;
    for(File f:files)
        f.delete();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `context.getCacheDir()`, you can you `context.getFilesDir()`. The reason is `getCacheDir()` is for storing light-weight cache file.

However, I strongly advise you to use a well-developed library such as Picasso or Glide for loading and caching images.